# Send request progress to client side via nodejs and express

Tags: node.js, express

I am using [this (contentful-export)](https://github.com/contentful/contentful-export) library in my express app like so

```
const app = require('express');

...

app.get('/export', (req, rex, next) => {
  const contentfulExport = require('contentful-export');
  const options = {
     ...
  }
  contentfulExport(options).then((result) => {
     res.send(result);
  });
})
```

now this does work, but the method takes a bit of time and sends status / progress messages to the node console, but I would like to keep the user updated also.. is there a way I can send the node console progress messages to the client??

This is my first time using node / express any help would be appreciated, I'm not sure if this already has an answer since im not entirely sure what to call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking of the documentation for contentful-export I don't think this is possible. The way this usually works in Node is that you have an object (`contentfulExport` in this case), you call a method on this object and the same object is also [an EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter). This way you'd get a hook to react to fired events.

```
// pseudo code
someLibrary.on('someEvent',  (event) => { /* do something */ })
someLibrary.doLongRunningTask()
  .then(/* ... */)
```

This is not documented for contentful-export so I assume that there is no way to hook into the log messages that are sent to the console.

Your question has another tricky angle though. In the code you shared you include a single endpoint (`/export`). If you would like to display updates or show some progress you'd probably need a second endpoint giving information about the progress of your long running task (which you can not access with contentful-export though).

The way this is usually handled is that you kick of a long running task via a certain HTTP endpoint and then use another endpoint that serves infos via polling or or a web socket connection.

Sorry that I can't give a proper solution but due to the limitation of contentful-export I don't think there is a clean/easy way to show progress of the exported data.

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for that! Id say your probably correct! will look into some other solutions

Comment: Happy to help. :)